# How to use user details after logging in?

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart

I created functions to log the user into my system via rest api. and everything works but I also want to use information about my user who has just logged in and display it on the main page or in the drawer, could anyone have any idea how to do it?

my code:

signIn function:

```
  signIn(String email, pass) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': pass
    };
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var response = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2:80/user/login", body: data);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if(jsonResponse != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        sharedPreferences.setInt("id", jsonResponse['id']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      print(response.body);
    }
  }
```

mainpage after successfully logged in to system:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoginStatus();
  }

  checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(sharedPreferences.getInt("id") == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Code Land", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              sharedPreferences.clear();
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            },
            child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("Main Page")),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

my user object:

```
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "admin",
  "lastName": "admin",
  "accountName": "Kot filemon",
  "email": "admin@admin.pl",
  "active": false,
  "activateCode": 0,
  "admin": true,
  "latitude": 000,
  "longitude": 000,
  "profileImage": null
```

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete detailed answer, but a way to describe a procedure you can follow.

---

Well, you can to store the user-info in your application. I see you are only saving the *ID* and using `sharedPreferences` in this line.

```
sharedPreferences.setInt("id", jsonResponse['id']);
```

You can save the other fields like this, using the same way that you use with the *ID*

```
sharedPreferences.setString("firstName", jsonResponse['firstName']);
sharedPreferences.setString("lastName", jsonResponse['lastName']);
sharedPreferences.setString("accountName", jsonResponse['accountName']);
sharedPreferences.setString("email", jsonResponse['email']);
```

---

Then, in your MainPage, you need to recover this data, "same way" you do in the function `checkLoginStatus()`.

You need a class for your `User()` to organize your data.

```
class User {
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String email;

  User({this.id, this.firstName, this.email});
}
```

A `getUser()` function, to retrieve your data using the `User` class

```
Future<User> getUser() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var id = sharedPreferences.getInt("id");
    var firstName = sharedPreferences.getString("firstName");
    var email = sharedPreferences.getString("email");

    return User(id: id, firstName: firstName, email: email);
  }
```

and in your initState() function, call this function like this:

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  Future<User> myUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoginStatus();
    myUser = getUser();
  }
```

The code is not tested !

Comment: thanks, can you show how this function to recovered this data should  look?

Comment: becauser when I use in my drawer, ```getString('firstName')``` it return me null

Comment: See my updated answer. The new code should help you more!